# How was Leo Bonhart from "The Witcher" able to kill three Witchers?

Tags: the-witcher

How was possible that Leo Bonhart, an "ordinary" human, was able to kill three Witchers?
Was he just well trained, or had magic to help him as well?

Comment: Of course it is. He was *very* experienced in fighting dangerous people. Also witchers while not using elixirs (and perhaps being to busy to use signs), weren't all that super, and differed in skill between each other.

Comment: "or did the magic help him as well?" What magic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leo Bonhart was a well-trained bounty hunter and previously a witch slayer. From witcher.fandom.com:

> Leo Bonhart (d. 1268) was a bounty hunter and previously a professional soldier from Ebbing. Known for his professionalism and expense to hire, he found pleasure in watching brutal scenes and inflicting pain on others. He was described as very tall but ghoulishly thin, with a prodigious grey moustache. He was said to have cold, expressionless eyes which were often likened to fish.

Thus Leo Bonhart is above "ordinary human" skill and expertise so it is very possible that he managed to kill 3 witchers during his life. Most witchers are not at Geralt's level and are weaker in comparison (as he was naturaly gifted) and the author doesn't reveal if Leo Bonhart had a fair fight against the 3 said witchers (meaning that he could've taken them by surprise, shot them with an arrow or they didn't use potions to enhance their power).

Comment: I'm pretty sure he duelled with each, so no dagger/ arrow/etc. in the back, but also no elixirs and Bonhart could still use some tactical advantages/circumstances.

Comment: since Bonhart is a hired bounty hunter, if he had been given a task to take out a witcher I presume he would'nt take any chances and use any means necessary, that is why i suppose he may have used surprize/devious tactics.

Comment: Ah, but he had some quirks. Was proud of his skill and of killing them, otherwise he could just sell medallions of fair price. I think his victories happened mainly because of his skill. So while he could do some things to even the odds, he did give them chance to win, like Ciri.could.

Comment: @Mithoron Of course, he is portrayed as an arrogant and a very cruel man and he bested many skilled swordsman and even groups of fighters. But as he is also cunning so that is why I said he could've resorted to other means that a straightforward sword fight against a witcher. But the author leaves that to the imagination :D

Answer (score 3):

Well, we must consider two things about Leo Bonhart: 
First thing, Leo Bonhart *claims* he killed three witchers. Nobody ever has proof: neither the characters, nor us, the readers. We can think a man like him, proud of his skills, wouldn't lie about such a thing... or would he?
Something Leo Bonhart also is: he's a ruthless pragmatic. And this bring us to our
Second thing: while he is clearly a very, **very** skilled swordsman, with a physique described as something out of continuous training and practice, the depictions of his fights also suggest something more: a lot of his victims are extremely *afraid* of him, some to the point of being terrorized by his mere sight.
As anyone fighting for sport or profession can attest, if you fear your opponent and think him invincible, you are already defeated.
While killing half a dozen people may seem an incredible feat, it actually isn't if those people are so terrorized by you that they are afraid to attack or they will do so in a mindless frenzy: And this is actually how most of the times Bonhart defeats his enemies: by striking fear in their hearts. 
Some he kills thanks to his skill, like in the last part of Lady of the Lake, but mostly he defeats his enemies by fear alone, the sword just doing the dirty work.
So, his "killed three witchers" boast can just be part of his "legend", that he built to make others think he's invincible. So that he is.

Answer (score -2):

I am a fan of the very unpopular theory that Leo Bonhart is some form of failed or renegade Witcher.

There are a few potential hints here and there in favour of this theory, in my opinion one of the most explicit is the following quote

“Ciri panted. She felt terror beginning to seize her. She understood what she was up against.”

In my view this is a hint that Bonhart is a special kind of person, and that Ciri recognised him as such.

There are also other more indirect hints at Bonhart being a far superior fighter than all other humans, for example when he dispatches Cahir - one of the best swordsmen in the story - quickly and with ease.

To me these hints and more point to Bonhart being clearly “super human” as a swordsman. And the above quote, where Ciri recognised his special nature, hints at something Ciri knew well…

Please don’t be mad at me for this controversial theory, I know is quite weak, still that’s the way I like to imagine Bonhart!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any stronger evidence you can cite?  Is it possible that Ciri simply recognized _him_ as opposed to something he may have been?

Comment: This seems like very weak beer on which to base a theory. She just recognises in him a confident swordsman.