# Was Leo Bonhart a witcher?

Tags: the-witcher

*(Saw this question in a russian forum and wanted to share it here.)*

Was Leo Bonhart a **witcher**?

1. He was in early senior age and still got an enourmous speed, strength and reaction.
2. Non-human fishy eyes.
3. He knew the wolf's school fighting style as he could recognize it from Ciri.
4. Was able to kill 3 other witchers.
5. > Killed Cahir way to easy and mentioned that Cahir have no chances against him, if he is not a witcher.
6. > Yennefer stabbed a fork in his face. A regular human would loose at least the ability to fight.

Comment: Duplicate of [Bonhart From The Witcher](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223578/bonhart-from-the-witcher)

Comment: @Valorum I don't see the questions as identical. My question is very precise and includes supporting arguments.

Comment: Yes, but any information relevant to this question can be (and would be) replicated there. Which means that this question is superfluous